# How to localize auto capitalization type of UITextField in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, uitextfield, capitalization

In my iOS app, I show a UITextField that is allowing the users to enter a book title.

However, users from the US would expect **UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords** (as each word should be capitalized) while users from Spain would expect **UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences** (as only the first word in a sentence should be capitalized).

Any suggestions how to target this?

Comment: In English titles, some words should remain lowercase – the, of, and, iOS, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programatically get the locale identifier from the code below

```
[NSLocale currentLocale].localeIdentifier
```

From the list of iOS identifiers defined [here](https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273), you can determine what you want, but it might fail if some user change their Region from device settings, which usually no one does, so this might work for you.

For your case you can add **en_US** for US and for Spanish there are 23 locales you need to define check the link above, so if the identifier fall in any one them you use them accordingly.

Cheers.

Comment: Actually, I care about the language more than about the location. I think I will just check for "en" to distinguish between English to other languages. Thanks for your help!